# stringstream >> operator does not take the next line

Tags: c++

```
void fill() {
ifstream fin;
fin.open(File);
if (!fin) {
    throw std::runtime_error("unable to open file");
}
char line[maximumCodeLine];
std::stringstream stream;
string letter;
string code;
while(readline(fin, line, maximumCodeLine, '\n')) {
    string str = string(line);
    stream.str(str);
    stream >> letter >> code;
    cout << letter << endl;
    cout << code << endl;

   // basically what i want to do finally 
   // create some object like --> object myObj(letter, code);
}   

}

bool readline(ifstream &fin, char *line, int linesize, char delim)
{
  if (fin.eof()) return false;  
  fin.getline(line, linesize, delim);
  if (!fin.good()) return false;
  int last = strlen(line) - 1;
  if (line >= 0 && line[last] == '\r') line[last] = '\0';
  return true;
}
```

I have text file containing the following

> abc 1234
>   ass 2345
>   dfd 3455

Basically, I want to create object taking two string parameters. Then I would get two words on the line of the text file and pass them into the object.

But when I print out the letter and code each time stream changes its string value, I get

> abc
>   1234
>   abc
>   1234
>   abc
>   1234

It means that letter and code value does not change.

I think `stream >> code and stream >> letter` has problem because I confirmed that the stream itself changes its string value during the while loop

How can I get the next word???

Comment: do `stream.clear();` before `stream.str(str);`

Comment: but why does it print the last twice ?? any idea?

Comment: i have got dfd 3455 dfd 3455

Comment: Check the contents of `line` in the last iteration, I suspect it's an empty line. You should always check if your stream extractions were successful: `if(stream >> letter >> code) { /* success */ }`